# Real life application math questions involving mass,volume,density

Tags: volume

An Oil tank has height of $2.55 m$ , radius of $1.05 m$, mass of $650 kg$. Safety information given tells us that the tank can be filled to a maximum of $90\%$ of its total volume.

The Oil tank can be modelled as a cylinder with a hemisphere on the top.

Additional informations:

Density of heating oil = $829 \frac{kg}{m^3}$

$1000 kg$ is equivalent to $9.81 kN$

The tank is never filled to more than its safe volume. It will need a special foundation of its total weight per square metre , on the ground beneath , is greater than $15 \frac{kN}{m^2}$ .
Given that the model is an underestimation of the actual volume of the tank , does the tank need a special foundation ? Justify the decision with calculations .

I'm Abit stunned right now on what to do with this ?

I found the actual volume of the tank is $5.3685 m^3$

As well as the weight per square metre on the ground is $6376.5 N$

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you get the volume. I get a different number
$V=V_{cyl}+V_{hem}=\pi r^2 h + 2 \pi /3 r^3=11.25 m^3$. The total mass is $m=m_{tank}+0.9*V*\rho_{oil}=9048.64 kg$. The force that the filled tank acts on the ground is then $88.77kN$, acting on a surface $\pi r^2$, so the pressure is $25.62 kN/m^2$